# glColor3f does not change the color

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm working on a Win32 app in C/C++ with SDL.
I have a weird problem with `glColor3f` command.
I want to print some text on my screen, it is working but the color of the text stay white.
The only way I have found so far to change the color is that : `glColor3f(255,0,0);`

I have tried this but the text still white :

```
// 1 try :
GLfloat Red = static_cast<GLfloat>(Objet.GetCouleurMenuRed()); // 255
GLfloat Green = static_cast<GLfloat>(Objet.GetCouleurMenuGreen()); // 0
GLfloat Blue = static_cast<GLfloat>(Objet.GetCouleurMenuBlue()); // 0
// 2 try :
float Red = static_cast<float>(Objet.GetCouleurMenuRed()); // 255
float Green = static_cast<float>(Objet.GetCouleurMenuGreen()); // 0
float Blue = static_cast<float>(Objet.GetCouleurMenuBlue()); // 0
// 3 try :
int Red = Objet.GetCouleurMenuRed(); // 255
int Green = Objet.GetCouleurMenuGreen(); // 0
int Blue = Objet.GetCouleurMenuBlue(); // 0

glColor3i(Red, Green, Blue); // --> Nothing on the screen
glColor3f(Red, Green, Blue); // --> Text OK but still white
```

I watch with a debug point the value in Red, Green, Blue : It is good.
So what is wrong with this?

EDIT : Thanks to derhass : works with glColor3ub();

Comment: This does not tell how you render the text. Using a texture? an external library? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: You are definitively using `glColor3i()` incorrectly. If your input range is 0-255, you should use `glColor3ub()`

Comment: Thanks derhass. It is working perfectly with glColor3ub().. But still weird that is working like this : glColor3f(255, 0, 0) and not like this glColor3f(Red, Green, Blue);

Comment: When you use `glColor3f`, each argument is *clamped* to `0.0`-`1.0` range. If argument is larger than `1`, it becomes `1`. If argument is smaller than `0`, it becomes `0`.
`1` means maximal amount of of specific color, `0` means minimal amount. It means, `glColor3f(255, 0, 0)` will give you same color as `glColor3f(1, 0, 0)`, but `glColor3f(0.99, 0, 0)` is different color.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will remember it ;)